# how to call class method in rspec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have following class method

```
module Abc
  class Def
    class << self
      include Ghi::Lmn
      def mymethod(*args)
      puts 'class method'

      def value
      @value.nil? ? 'test' << name : @value
      end
      end
  end
end
```

now how can i write test cases for this method so it will call method mymethod?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20120917073754/http://posterous.timocracy.com/a-pattern-for-testing-class-methods-in-ruby-w) a good link on how to call a class method with `rspec`. Basically you create a call to the class method in the `rspec` itself:

```
class FooBar

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end

  def output
    puts @foo
    puts @bar
  end

end

describe Foo do
  context bar do
    subject { FooBar.new(<info>).output } # Create an instance of the class in the rspec
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a class method, not an instance method.

Comment: Thanks. is there any way i could also access name coming from Ghi::Lmn?
 updated question

Comment: You know, honestly idk, that's a good question though, you should ask it! I'd love to find out the answer. I'd assume you'd just access it from the call itself like you normally would `Foo::Barr.<method>`

Answer (score 0):

You can call your method like this:

```
Abc::Def.mymethod(1, 2, 3, :foo, :bar, :baz)
```